# How to easily move icon in Expansion panel header to right in Vuetify?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

Using template from this example: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/#usage

I get header icon sticked to the title

"float: right;", doesn't help

did anyone encounter this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wthAu.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think enabling `RTL` mode in a bad way cause this problem. Add this code to your CSS:

```
.v-expansion-panel-header__icon {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```